# Methods calling in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, scope

I found this code in [CanCan gem](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Abilities-in-Database) for rails:

```
def initialize(user)
    can do |action, subject_class, subject|
      user.permissions.find_all_by_action(aliases_for_action(action)).any? do |permission|
        permission.subject_class == subject_class.to_s &&
          (subject.nil? || permission.subject_id.nil? || permission.subject_id == subject.id)
      end
    end
  end
```

I understand that method can be called many times, but how are parameters passed? Where are the variables `action`, `subject_class`, and `subject` initiated?

Comment: The can method yields those parameters - read up on blocks.

Comment: Thanks, Frederick. That's what I need.

Answer (score 0):

From the example given in the cancan wiki, there is following models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :permissions
end

class Permissions < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

`action`, `subject_class` and `subject_id` are the columns in database on `permissions` table & `permission` model for which `ActiveRecord` auto-generates methods on model object. so for example

```
@permission = Permission.new
@permission.action = :new
@permission.subject_class = :ApplicationController
@permission.save
```

this will save this data in permissions table

Further,

- `action` = the specific action like index, edit, delete etc.
- `subject_class` = is the name of controller like `ApplicationController`
- `subject_id` = optional

Comment: This I understand. Confuse me code in question. Can - method that initiate current session permission. ok. But how work this code? It run method can many times? Where parameters is passed? Actually I think this is problem that I don't fully understand ruby syntax